# Linking error in xcode while loading it to the device

Tags: objective-c, ios-simulator, device

I am able to run my project in the simulator and it is working fine and is not giving any errors, but when i am trying to run the same application in the device, i.e while archieve, it is showing the following error,

```
ld: library not found for -lCorePlot-CocoaTouch
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

What is the mistake i am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the CorePlot library is not being built for the target architecture? For example, if you are building both for armv6 and armv7 and CorePlot is only being built for armv7, you would get this error. See the architecture build settings for your targets.

Comment: Even for CorePlot library the architecture is set to both armv6 and armv7.